# Why doesn't the Sequence Container have an error flow?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and I was wondering why the Sequence Container does'n't have an error flow, (red arrow)?
Instead, when I want to rollback, I have to use an Event Handler? At the moment, I am putting all my data flow tasks in the sequence container and using an sql script to begin and commit transactions before and after the containers. Hence, if it fails, I just use a "rollback" event on handler.

Is this the way to do it?

I don't want to use the MSDTC for transactions.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your transactions commit? Have you checked `@@TRANCOUNT`?

Comment: I guess because a sequence container can't really fail.   Only the stuff inside it can.  And by the way, couldn't you just make the dataflows atomic by setting their isolation levels?  I thought SSIS packages inherently ran in a transaction without explicitly starting/committing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use [TSQL Transactions](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/09/ssis-transactions-with-tsql.html) like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sequence container does have an error flow, but you have to set it manually. Doubleclick the green arrow you want red - and set the value to false.